# When does this parametric curve cross itself?

Tags: plane-curves, parametric

> Find the points where the curve given parametrically by$$\mathbf{r}(t)=\left(2+\cos\frac{3}{2}t\right)\left(\begin{matrix}\cos t\\\sin t\end{matrix}\right)$$crosses itself.

So, I understand that I should consider this equation$$\mathbf{r}(t_1)=\mathbf{r}(t_2),$$ which essentially is$$\left(2+\cos\frac{3}{2}t_1\right)\cos t_1=\left(2+\cos\frac{3}{2}t_2\right)\cos t_2$$and $$\left(2+\cos\frac{3}{2}t_1\right)\sin t_1=\left(2+\cos\frac{3}{2}t_2\right)\sin t_2,$$ but then I don't really know how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated, especially if it's in the form of hints.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that $t\in [0,4\pi]$, which I guess simplifies things.

Comment: give yourself an idea with [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot+%28%282%2Bcos%283t%2F2%29%29cos+t%2C+%282%2Bcos%283t%2F2%29sint%29 ]

Comment: or contrling $t$ [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot+%28%282%2Bcos%283t%2F2%29%29cos+t%2C+%282%2Bcos%283t%2F2%29sint%29%2C+%7Bt%2C0%2C8%7D ]

Comment: @janmarqz: you need one more () for $y$.

Comment: done [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot+%28%282%2Bcos%283t%2F2%29%29cos+t%2C+%28%282%2Bcos%283t%2F2%29%29sint%29 ]

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $2 + \cos x$ is never zero, so you can divide the first equation by the second. What do you get?

Comment: Yes, I actually did something similar and divided the second by the first. But then I get $\tan t_1=\tan t_2$, provided that $\cos t_1,\cos t_2\neq 0$. However, this implies that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are a distance $\pi$ apart and this doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @Ryuky First, why $\cos t_1 \neq \cos t_2?$ Second, what's incorrect about it?

Comment: @Rivin Sorry I got confused. I meant that none of the cosines should be zero. I guess my problem is that the fact that $t_1$ and $t_2$ are a distance $\pi$ apart doesn't tell me (or at least I don't see it) how to get the Cartesian points of self-intersection.

Comment: @Ryuky but don't forget that $\cos \frac32 t_1 = \cos \frac 32 t_2$ also.

Comment: @Rivin which means that I want either $t_1=\pi k + t_2$ or $t_1=3/2 t_2 + 2\pi k $, right?

Comment: @Ryuky no, you want BOTH the conditions, not necessarily with the same $k.$

Answer (score 0):

If you write down the parametric equation in polar coordinates instead of cartesian ones, you will immediately see that you need $t_1+2\pi = t_2$ (or vice versa) as well as
$2+\cos \frac 32t_1 = 2+\cos\frac 32 t_2$.
But 
$$\cos \frac 32t_2 = \cos(\frac 32 t_1 + 3\pi) = \cos(\frac 32 t_1 + \pi) = -\cos(\frac 32 t_1)$$
so $\cos\frac 32 t_1 = 0$ ...